# JS replace long text with a smaller one

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to replace substring inside a string into a smaller string of the same type. For example :

`This is a long text ------------------------------- . A sentence`

So we see that `-` is repeated many time, I want to replace it to a smaller chuck `----------` (10 times)

This is what I tried `content = content.replace(/(-){20,}/, '$1');` but it only replace into one `-`

I also want it to work with all characters possible (only if they repeat) and not just with the dash.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(-{10})-+
```

You can use this and replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/22

EDIT:

```
((.)\2{9})\2+
```

See demo.This will work for all.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/23

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `$1`:

```
content.replace(/(-){20,}/g, '----------');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ggbe2f5x/

Comment: It would work but it doesn't work for all character, so we need to know the character in advance to do that

Comment: Great, you beat me with this! ;) ;)

Comment: @ThanhTrung Didn't get you. Can you explain with an example. BTW, you can add `g` global flag

Comment: @Tushar What about `azd -------------- aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccc .............................. vr` ?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```js
str = "" + 
  "foo ------------------------------------" + 
  "bar @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" +
  "baz ====================================";

maxLen = 3;

str = str.replace(/(.)\1{19,}/g, function($0) {
  return $0.substr(0, maxLen);
});

document.write(str)
```

Comment: This definitely the best answer! Could you explain `\1` ? Im not good with regex